# Unsupported SysV option when invoking ps

Tags: process

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 today. Every time I invoke *ps*, no matter what option I use, it always says

> ERROR: Unsupported SysV option.

and then prints the help.

Do you know how to make *ps* work correctly or what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you maybe have an alias for ps that has some invalid options?

Check by running `alias` on a terminal.

Also, ensure that you're running the correct ps and not a version installed elsewhere. ps should be in `/bin/ps` and `dpkg -S /bin/ps` should say it belongs to the procps package.

Finally, if you really want to ensure your ps is what it should be, install debsums and do

```
debsums procps
```

it should return 'OK' for all files in the package.

Comment: It was a wrong alias. I took some alias I use from an other computer and I didn't noticed that ps alias! Sorry and a lot of thanks for your help!